# aggregate dates based on duplicates

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-6

so i want to present a chart of pie, and present sum of comment in
 each day, for that i would like to sum each day in the last 7 days.
This is what i tried to do:

```
IEnumerable<DateTime> commentList;
        commentList = await _context.Commentdb.Select(a => a.dateSubmit)
            .GroupBy(b => b.Day).ToListAsync();
```

but its not working, instead its display this ERROR:

```
 Cannot implicity convert type List<int,DateTime> to List<DateTime>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to Group by  date and day before doing select.

```
IEnumerable<DateTime> commentList;
    commentList = await _context.Commentdb.GroupBy(b => new { b.Day, b.dateSubmit }).Select(a => a.Key.dateSubmit)
        .ToListAsync();
```

**Update :**

```
 IEnumerable<DateTime> commentList;
    commentList = await _context.Commentdb.Where(x => x.dateSubmit.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday ||x.dateSubmit.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday).GroupBy(b => new { b.Day, b.dateSubmit }).Select(a => a.Key.dateSubmit)
        .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: thank you !
if i would like to return only items that are from sunday to saturday of the current week.
how coud i do that with 'Where'?